# This function should work to calculate factorials, but it doesn't. [python-3.x]

Tags: function, math, python-3.x, factorial

(Full disclosure, I am going through the Python tutorial at CodeAcademy, and am using their web-based IDE.)

```
def factorial(x):
    bang = 1
        for num in x:
            bang = bang * num
    return bang
```

In java, this works to generate a factorial from a number smaller than 2,147,483,647. I think it should work in python, but it doesn't. Instead I get the error:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 3, in factorial
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Perhaps there's something I'm not understanding here, or perhaps my syntax is wrong. I tested further and created a separate function called factorial that iterates:

```
def factorial(x):
    if x > 2:
        return x
    else:
        return x(factorial(x-1))
```

This also doesn't work, giving me the error:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 11, in factorial
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

I am a python noob, but it seems that both of these should work. Please advise on the best way to learn Python syntax...

Comment: What did you think that `x(factorial(x-1))` means? To Python (and most other procedural languages), it would think you were calling `x` as a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do `for num in x` if `x` is an integer. An integer isn't "iterable" as the error says. You want something like this:

```
def factorial(x):
    bang = 1
    for num in xrange(1, x+1):
        bang = bang * num
    return bang
```

The `xrange` (or `range`) will generate the necessary range of numbers for the `in` to operate upon.

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(x):
        if x < 2:
            return 1
        else:
            return x * f(x - 1)
```

Comment: `factorial(0)` should be `1`, not `0`.